# Couchbase Indexing after server reboot

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rabbitmq, couchbase, nosql

Yesterday I rebooted Linux server where our Couchbase Server is installed. Once couchbase server had fully loaded and indexed the views, we noticed that some of the pages created by users were missing on the website. And instead of showing latest pages created on the website it was showing pages from 2014 and before as well as new pages after the reboot.

I assume this may be because of incomplete indexing of views after reboot, I might be wrong.

Can anyone help me figure out what is the problem and how this can be sorted?

thank you